# Karma: how to mock global variable that is declared in html?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a variable declared in html as

```
<script>
    var actionUrl = '@Url.Action(action, "Designer")';
</script>
```

so that the variable actionUrl can be called in the javascript file I want to test. 
However, as the unit test isolates each file to test, the actionUrl becomes undefined in karma. How do I mock this variable? What is the best practice?

Comment: By defining it in your test? `var actionUrl = 'whatever';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As suggested, by calling `window.actionUrl = 'whatever';`
2. Or maybe it'd make sense to invent some structure for mock-objects

`unit-tests
     |
   mocks - 
         | - module1.js
        ...
         | - moduleN.js
         | - globals.js`

and then put all global objects in `globals.js` and load it inside `karma.config.js`

Edit: added global mocks to the fork of Angular Seed https://github.com/sbedulin/angular-js-dev-guide

Comment: I tried to just define my variable inside karma.config.js but it still complains in the test that it's undefined, I've also defined it inside the test at the top of the file and inside the testing function but all fails...

Comment: Please check this commit of mine pushed to the fork of Angular Seed project https://github.com/sbedulin/angular-js-dev-guide/commit/d98a81355720e4ff595d8dedfb2cb170daa7bbd8

Comment: Sooo @OZZIE have you already tried to run angular seed tests with the above changes?